# Redirect all PDFs, but dont allow the pdfviewer to be redirected

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have following scenario:

- I want all PDFs redirected to the `/PDF/` directory
- but all PDFs requested in `/PDF/` should not be redirected

My idea was the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "!^/PDF"
RewriteRule "(.*)\.pdf" "/PDF/?file=%{REQUEST_URI}" [R=301,L]
```

For example if I open `http://example.com/some/path/a.pdf`. It redirects me to `http://example.com/PDF/?file=/some/path/a.pdf`, but then it should load the PDF but the same redirect occurs there too.

But for some reason it doesn't work. Has anyone a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule with a negative lookahead:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/PDF/
RewriteRule ^/(?!PDF/).+\.pdf$ /PDF/?file=$0 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

`(?!PDF/)` is negative lookahead to ignore URIs that already have `/PDF/` at the start.

Comment: it mostly worked but gave me a status `400 Bad Request`

Comment: it is a conf in the /etc/apache2/ folder and is included in the default-ssl.conf

Comment: it is everything i have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231757/discussion-between-play-it-and-anubhava).